# Azure SQL - check resource consumption by Table

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table in SQL DB which I know it has a very large number of WRITES into it per day, at the same time our Database often timeout due to insufficient amount of Memory and CPU (it's called DTU, in Azure terminology)

I am wondering how much CPU, Memory can our DB saves if this table were to be completely dropped? Is there a way to calculate the cost of all READS/WRITES agains a specific table in SQL Server?

Comment: "*insufficient amount of Memory and CPU*" - This likely is not really related to the high number of writes to the table. But what can be related to the timeouts is excessive locking / blocking because the table is being constantly written to (but then it's not an issue with Memory or CPU consumption).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LOG\_RATE\_GOVERNOR Wait Stat](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186211/log-rate-governor-wait-stat) --- Write-heavy tables tend to hit the log rate governor, as transaction log IO is one of the components that makes up a DTU.

Comment: @AMtwo Nice, you're probably right that in his case the DTU limit he's running into is due to I/O consumption (whether it be data, log, or the combination of both).

Comment: Query Store will help you aggregate resource consumption by query, and from there you could probably figure it out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16